# No Sound Through HDMI

Tags: debian, audio, hdmi

The problem I have is there is no sound on the HDMI port. I get video, but no sound.

aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

speaker-test -c 2 -l 1 -D hw:0,3 does NOT produce sound.

pacmd list-cards

```
2 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_01.1>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 6
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfeb44000 irq 38"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:01.1"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "1002"
    device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    device.product.id = "9902"
    device.product.name = "Trinity HDMI Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <off>
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 7
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb40000 irq 16"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "1022"
    device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
    device.product.id = "780d"
    device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: no)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: no)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: no)
    output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5560, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.iec958-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.iec958-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

Relevant part of lspci -v

```
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
    Memory at feb44000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Have you checked the volume with `alsamixer`? Are you attempting to play audio via HDMI after "connecting" the video output with `xrandr`? Are you using ALSA directly *only*, or are you using a sound daemon such as PulseAudio?

Comment: Whoops, still trying to figure out how to use the site.
In alsamixer I hit F6 and choose "HDA ATI HDMI" - it shows a box with S/PDIF with a small box above it that has 00 in it. I can't seem to do anything else with it.
When I start xrandr I see this:
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1360 x 768, maximum 1360 x 768
default connected primary 1360x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       0.00* 
   1280x720       0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00 
How would I determine which I am using?

Comment: There are hdmi cables up to version 3, if memory does not betray me. The regular 2USD v2? cable in aliexpress does not carry sound

Comment: `xrandr` makes my brain hurt, so I use the `arandr` front-end GUI :) Once you get HDMI video connected, the audio connection should no longer show "unplugged" in PulseAudio.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! I wasn't able to figure it out. I ended up buying a new graphics card and it worked straight out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when, after wake up, all HDMI sound outputs / sinks are either "unplugged", "unavailable" or just gone :

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --set "audio" on
```

Note : Everything else **failed**, including

- Log out and back in
- Delete `~/.config/pulseaudio/*`
- `pulseaudio -k`
- `pulseaudio --start`
- `pulseaudio -D`
- Any combination of the above points

The only thing I did / will not try is to run pulseaudio in system-wide mode.